# How to i access json respond code in php

Tags: php, json

```
$url_api = 'https://example.com/api?signature='.$signature.'&token='.$token.'&jsfile='.$jsurl.'';
$alishsig = file_get_contents($url_api);header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $alishsig ;
```

**and output is**

> {"code":200,"decodedSignature":"768016F1B82C0ECC54BE0629EDB2B52538F01.01AB221ADD7969CEA2FA105BD78DF3294FE6D"}

How to i access only decoded signature like this only

```
68016F1B82C0ECC54BE0629EDB2B52538F01.01AB221ADD7969CEA2FA105BD78DF3294FE6D
```

Comment: `$alishsig['decodedSignature'];` does this work? - also your question is very bare, not much info and quite messy. In the future include more information/code/examples.

Comment: Try Hassaan's answer as you need to build the JSON array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$alishsig = json_decode($alishsig, false);  
echo $alishsig->decodedSignature;
```